# Orbeon index of repeat in repeatable section

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have repeatable section (not repeater) and inside it I have ouput field. How can I put the repeat index to this output? I want to bind outputs with index of current iteration. For example if I add 5 repeats I want to outputs show their index: 1,2,3,4,5. I know that there is functions like xxf:index, but they work only in repeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not obvious because the `xxf:repeat-position()` function works in the UI only, and the calculated values work in the model only.

You could make changes by hand and write:

`<xf:output value="xxf:repeat-position()"/>`