# How to refer to relevant repeated node position based to another repeated node position in Orbeon?

Tags: xpath, repeater, orbeon, xforms, xpath-2.0

I  created a form with a repeat to show a list of data.But not all row elements are from same nodeset!
The table is created based the number of Student nodes:

```
...
<Student>
<Firstname>Kostas</Firstname>
<Lastname>Oikonomopoulos</Lastname>
</Student>
<Student>
<Firstname>Teo</Firstname>
<Lastname>Kartsonas</Lastname>
</Student>
...
<Math>
<Name>Mathematics</Name>
<Grade>Class A</Class>
</Math>
<Math>
<Name>Physics</Name>
<Class>Class B</Class>
</Math>
...
```

So i want to create a repeated grid like this:

```
Headers -Lastname-          -Firstname-  -Lesson-         -Class-
1# ---- Oikonomopoulos ---- Kostas  ---- Mathematics ---- Class A
2# ---- Kartsonas      ---- Teo     ---- Physics     ---- Class B
```

Where the data list consists of each row for every student, and each student has a lesson and a class for this lesson based the relative position of the student!

So i want in each row:

```
//(Student)[i]/Firstname, //(Student)[i]/Lastname, //(Math)[i]/Name, //(Math)[i]/Class
```

where `i` is the position of the each Student node iteration.

I create the data table  using **xf:repeat** :

```
...
<xf:repeat ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//Student">
...
...
<xh:td>
<xf:output ref="Firstname"/>
</xh:td>
<xh:td>
<xf:output ref="Lastname"/>
</xh:td>
...
<xh:td>
<xf:output ref="(//Math)[position()]/Name"/>
</xh:td>
<xh:td>
<xf:output ref="(//Math)[position()]/Class"/>
</xh:td>
...
```

The students are shown as expected, but lessons and the classes have same values for all iterations!Like:

```
Headers -Lastname-          -Firstname-  -Lesson-                      -Class-
1# ---- Oikonomopoulos ---- Kostas  ---- Mathematics ------------------ Class A
2# ---- Kartsonas      ---- Teo     ---- Mathematics (wrongValue!) ---- Class A (wrongValue!)
```

The weird thing is that if the position() alone as output in a column, correctly shows 1,2,...!?!
*I am using Orbeon 4.5*

Comment: Can you use variables to store XPath values? In that case store the position() and use e.g. with XSLT you would use `<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>` and then `<xf:output ref="(//Math)[$pos]/Name"/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the situation that the nodeset we want to refer are outside the repeated nodeset, the *position()* function **doesn't work in calculations** as i expected. 
Instead the solution was to use *[xxf:repeat-position()](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-xpath-functions#TOC-xxf:repeat-position-)* function!

So instead of, 
 `<xf:output ref="(//Math)[position()]/Name"/>`

, the proper way is: 
`<xf:output ref="(//Math)[xxf:repeat-position()]/Name"/>`

[*xxf:repeat-position()* function works in the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607637/orbeon-index-of-repeat-in-repeatable-section?rq=1)

```
<xf:output value="xxf:repeat-position()"/>
```